# password encryption in django using serializer(drf)

Tags: django-rest-framework

models.py

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, name='contact_no')
    token_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, name='role')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'contact_no', 'role',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of profile
        :return: returns a successfully created profile record
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(),validated_data=user_data)
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, contact_no=validated_data.pop('contact_no'),
                                                                role=validated_data.pop('role'))
        return profile
```

views.py

```
class UserRecordsView(APIView):

    """
    A class based view for creating and fetching profile records
    """
    def get(self, request):
        """
        Get all the student records
        :param format: Format of the profile records to return to
        :return: Returns a list of profile records
        """
        profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
        }
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(profiles, many=True, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        :User and User Profile Creation .
        :param request:
        :return:
       """
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here password is in the form of text ,i want encrypted form of password.here one to one relation is there between user and userprofile table.i want to create user and userprofile data by only one method, that's why i need to encrypt password also at the same time only.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'contact_no', 'role',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of profile
        :return: returns a successfully created profile record
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(),validated_data=user_data)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, contact_no=validated_data.pop('contact_no'),
                                                                role=validated_data.pop('role'))
        return profile
```

we need to add only two lines to get the encrypted password here.

```
user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
```